# How to add Phaser plugins?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Why don't I get to reduce CPU using Phaser plugin or what wrong with the code?

```
<script src="assets/js/phaser.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/SaveCPU.js"></script>

var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 726, Phaser.AUTO, 'container',{preload: gPreload, create: create});

function create() {
  this.game.plugins.add(new Phaser.Plugin.SaveCPU)
}
```

Comment: The CPU usage is not reduce and lack of documentation on how to add plugin to the code. Please advice.

Answer (score 4):

See my example to add Phaser plugins:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(1024, 768, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
    init: function () {

        //Load the plugin
        this.game.kineticScrolling = this.game.plugins.add(Phaser.Plugin.KineticScrolling);
    }
});
```

the plugin of this example is: http://jdnichollsc.github.io/Phaser-Kinetic-Scrolling-Plugin/

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't use SaveCPU.js just because there is no documentation on github. There are actually two issues posted on its GitHub repository so don't bother using the plugin.

If you need to reduce the CPU load you should just refactor your code.